# Java converting an object to his superclass and then converting it back to itself keeps the reference

Tags: java

My question is, how is this situation possible?

How is it possible that i can access the value of the text variable from a class of B type?

Is the 'testB' object keeping a reference to the 'testA' object?

CODE:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A testA = new A();
        testA.text = "Test";

        B testB = testA;

        System.out.println(((A)testB).text); // This prints "Test"
    }
}

class A extends B {
    public String text = "";

    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

class B {

    public String foo2() {
        return "foo 2";
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You do not convert anything. The only thing that "changes" (although, not really, since they are defined as such) are the static types of the variables/parameters used. All references reference the same object

Comment: You're not converting anything. You're only referencing a unique object using two different classes. Just like I can say "Oh, here's a pen. I'll give you this object". And then you can say "thanks for this object. Oh, it's a pen". There's a unique object here: a pen. And sometimes I and you refer to it as an object, and sometimes as a pen. Whatever the way we talk about it, it is, and will always be a pen.

Comment: So `A` extends `B`. This means you can assign `testA` to `testB`, but it doesn't change the underlying object, it only makes `testB` point to what ever `testA` is pointing to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down this code for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A testA = new A();
    testA.text = "Test";

    B testB = testA;

    System.out.println(((A)testB).text); // This prints "Test"
}
```

Starting with:

```
A testA = new A();
```

You start off by initializing memory of class of 'A' as a new Object of 'A', or in other words, you have created an area within your RAM that is held by an object of class A.

```
testA.text = "Test";
```

You then set its property of text to the string literal "Test"

and lastly you initialize memory of class 'B' as a reference to your object 'A'

```
B testB = testA;
```

The reason you cannot access the text property without the cast is because testB does not have the property 'text', e.g. the properties and methods you can access are determined by your initialization (B testB gives access to the methods and properties of class B). When acting upon an object with a method however (e.g. myMethod(myClass class)), how that method behaves is determined by what type of object it is. This is a core concept of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

The most common use of polymorphism is the ability of an object to take the form of another object, so it refers to a child class object.

In the code you've posted class A is a subclass of class B. So after the assignment, the object B takes the form of the object A and eventually refers to its memory block. Hence, it returns the value of its text attribute, no matter if you cast it to class A or not.